# Programmatically scrolling to and coloring a UITableViewCell at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController` which contains a list of items. Now, I want the list to be automatically scrolled to a item (index = `bestOne` ) once the view appears. Meanwhile I want the item to be colored into red and be labeled as `Marked`.

My code roughly achieves what I want. But, I actually see more than one red items **iterating**: every 10 items, there is a red item.

I am quite new to iphone development, I figure it might have something to do with reusable cells. But I am not exactly sure why. Can anybody suggest one way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.bestOne != -1)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.bestOne inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: atScrollPosition: animated:YES];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == self.bestOne)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Marked";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the reusable cells part.

Your code should be something like –

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.row == self.bestOne)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Marked";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else 
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
}
```

On reuse, you get the exact cell that you had set before. While other cells are undistinguishable, the marked cell stands out with its specifically set `detailTextLabel`. You need to reset it before you can use it as an unmarked cell.

Comment: Don't forget to reset the `textLabel.textColor` !

Comment: @Zeiga, @thelaws is right. I didn't add `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];` because I mistook it to be `detailTextLabel`. You should add it too.

Answer (score 0):

you look like you are on the right track with the color issue, you may accumulate red colored text cells, if you aren't calling `[tableView reloadData]` or reloading the old  red cells specifically, which you would want to do if you have a large table. your scrolling looks good, don't know why that wouldn't work.